# All of the lists are coming out empty?

Tags: python, database, list

I dont know if I am doing something wrong with the way I am laying out the functions or what. Basically I am trying to send a list of tickers to a database. I am taking the difference of two list so that the one that I send doesnt have the same tickers as the previous send. Can anyone help me?

```
tickList=[]
compareList=[]
newestList=[]

def searchTwit():
    tweets = api.search("#stocks",count=100)
    return tweets 

def Diff(li1, li2):
    return (list(list(set(li1)-set(li2)) + list(set(li2)-set(li1))))

def getTicker(tweets,list1,list2,anyList):
    for tweet in tweets:
        if "$" in tweet.text:
            x = tweet.text.split()
            for i in x:
                if i.startswith("$") and i[1].isalpha():
                    i.strip(".")
                    i.upper()
                    list1.append(i)
    anyList = Diff(list1,list2)
    #print(newestList)
    list2=list1
    #print(list2)
    list1.clear()
    #print(list1)
    return(anyList)

def retrieveTickers(list):
    for i in list:
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO master.dbo.TickerTable (TickerName) VALUES (?);', (i))
    conn.commit()

while True:
    sleep(60 - time() %60)
    print(f'This is ticklist {tickList}')
    print(f'This is  compareList{compareList}')
    print(f'This is newestList {newestList}')
    full_tweets=searchTwit()
    getTicker(full_tweets,tickList,compareList,newestList)
    retrieveTickers(newestList)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Please provide example inputs with corresponding outputs, and the output you were *expecting*.

Comment: What is the purpose of '''anyList'''? It gets overwritten in your getTicker function

Answer (score 0):

There are a few places that seem incorrect.

Python strings are immutable so this code block isn't doing what you think.

```
i.strip(".")
i.upper()
list1.append(i)
```

The string manipulation functions return new strings so you need to do this:

```
list1.append(i.strip(".").upper())
```

Its super unclear what you want `retrieveTickers` to do since its actually writing to a database. The function verb should match the action.

The `diff` function is convoluted. It can be simplified to

```
(set(li1) | set(li2)) - (set(li1) & set(li2))
```

but I don't see where you need these to be ordered so I would recommend changing the type you standardize on to set then `diff` can be written as:

```
li1.symmetric_difference(li2)
```

which probably doesn't need to be a function.

This block:

```
full_tweets=searchTwit()
getTicker(full_tweets,tickList,compareList,newestList)
retrieveTickers(newestList)
```

is also really really hard to follow. I think you are trying to manipulate the lists within the getTicker function. I **strongly** recommend not doing this. Instead return the information you need and if you need more than one data structure return them as a tuple. If I understand this correctly your function signature should probably look more like this:

```
new_tickers, already_seen_data = \
    getTicker(full_tweets, already_seen_data)
```

Comment: thank you so much @gph , that helped a lot. I am kind of new to actually using function so this is really helpful